# Xpath - get only node content without other elements

Tags: xpath

I have an `div` elemet:

```
<div>
   This is some text
   <h1>This is a title</h1>
   <div>Some other content</div>
</div>
```

What xpath expression should I use to only get the `div` content without his child elements
`h1` and `div`

`//div[not(h1)&not(div)]`

Something like that? I cannot figure it out

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for three XPath expressions that probably provide you with the not defined by you "content" of the `div` element.

Answer (score 62):

**To get the string value of `div` use**:

```
string(/div)
```

This is the concatenation of all text nodes that are descendents of the (top) `div` element.

**To select all text node descendents of `div` use**:

```
/div//text()
```

**To get only the text nodes that are direct children of `div` use**:

```
/div/text()
```

**Finally, get the first (and hopefully only) non-whitespace-only text node child of `div`**:

```
/div/text()[normalize-space()][1]
```

Comment: Your answer only shows how to get text of either parent node AND it's descendants, or descendants only. I'm sure the question was how to get ONLY parent node text, without descendants (e.g. `This is some text` in example given in question)

Comment: @EduardSukharev, The answer correctly provides this expression: `/div/text()` In general one may not know exactly which of the text-node children of `div` is the wanted one. There may be other, whitespace-only nodes. So, one has to provide the position of the node they are interested in... In case it is specified that only one text child node of `div` is a non-whitespace-only node, then the expression to select this node is:

`/div/text()[not(normalize-space())][1]`

I have edited the question. Please reverse your downvote and consider upvoting now.

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood `text nodes` as just `nodes`, which is obviously not what you meant. And, yes, your answer is correct, full and thorough. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

> What xpath expression should I use to
>   only get the `div` content without his
>   child elements `h1` and `div`

This XPath expression:

```
/div/node()[not(self::h1|self::div)]
```

It selects every `div` root element's children except those `h1` or `div` elements.

Answer (score 5):

expression like **./text()** will retrieve only the content of root element only.

Regards,
Nitin

Answer (score 2):

**You can use this XPath expression:**

```
./div[1]/text()[1]
```

to test, I use this online tester : http://xpather.com/