# How can I get text without links?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have some div with text and links.

```
<div id="mydiv">
some text <a href="#">super link</a> la la la
</div>
```

I need to get output with xPath:

```
some text la la la
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xpath - get only node content without other elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455684/xpath-get-only-node-content-without-other-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you want that ***string value*** of the `div`:

```
string(//div[@id="mydiv"])
```

will return

```
some text la la la
```

as requested.